# Abort a multi-file latexmk run entirely, on all files at once?

Tags: latexmk

I usually use a `latexmkrc` file to specify the default master files of a project, so that I can just invoke `latexmk` without specifying files.  But sometimes I accidentally do the same in a multi-file project without a `latexmkrc`, so it tries to compile every `.tex` file, most of which will of course throw errors.

Of course, when this happens, I’d like to abort the whole run.  However, the only thing I’ve found is to go through aborting each file individually with `x` after it errors.  Standard kill commands like `ctrl-D` also seem to only abort one file at a time.  In a large project, going through all files this way be quite tedious.  **Is there a quick way to abort the whole `latexmk` run at once?**

Just in case it’s relevant: I’m working from the `zsh` shell, on Mac OS 12.6.5.